# how to use periods in URL in a vite/vue generated project?

Tags: vue.js, vite

using create-vue, which generates a brand new project (latest versions), which also uses vite instead of webpack, instantly crashes throwing a 404 if you have a dot in the URI. it is not like this with vueCLI webpack.

likely a vite bug????

Comment: Nobody can tell without additional details. If the dot is inside the domain/hostname - perhaps your DNS resolver can't resolve the resulting domain name ?

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2415